# Python: Dump DB into .txt file

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm new to programming in general, and I have a .py db that I was tasked with dumping into a .txt file that I can then use in ROOT to create a histogram of the data.

I'm sorry that I can't be too specific about this, but I know that the data comes from a MySQL DB and I was told to use Python to "easily" dump the data into a .txt file.

I have thus far tried

```
python /path/to/script.py > /path/to/output/myfile.txt
```

but it says that the directory of the output does not exist.

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM /path/to/script.py
--> INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/output/myfile.txt';
```

but my access to the server was denied.

I'm sure there must be a really simple way in Python to simply dump all the data into a .txt file, but I simply cannot find it.

Comment: If `script.py` is what you're meant to use why not output to a directory that **does** exist?

Comment: 1. use `mysqldump` to dump data from mysql. 2. create folders before putting files in them using `mkdir -p folder/path/`

Comment: The thing is that I'm accessing the data from mysql remotely so that I could copy the python dump and then from the .py file create a .txt file. I've tried creating folders and even trying to put the file into already existing directories, and it still says that they don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an error saying the folder does not exist, make sure you create the folder using [`mkdir`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir) prior to creating a file inside the folder:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/output/
```

Now that the folder does exist you can run:

```
python /path/to/script.py > /path/to/output/myfile.txt
```

The `-p` flag will make the command not fail if folder exists, and create all necessary parents of the folder you intend to write to:

```
-p, --parents
      no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Also, from the title of your question it seems like you want to dump the entire database, or perhaps some tables. There is a tool that does just that and it's called [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). Don't re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: I explained above in other comments, I don't have access to the actual mysql database, only a snapshot of it that was dumped into a .py file.

Comment: I tried this: python snapshotSmartCacheDb.py > snapshotSmartCacheDb.txt and it seemed to work, but I don't know where to find the .txt file that seems to have been created?

Comment: can you show what is actually in the python script? (you can leave out specific data)

Comment: Mysql> select * from DatasetStatus       
 --> dset="" nused=1          and several hundred entries like the above follow

Comment: I am not familiar with this brand of python.

Comment: I was actually just able to figure it out and was able to create the .txt file, thank you!

Comment: can you share your solution for those who may run into a similar problem?

Comment: I used `python /home/gteix/snapshotSmartCacheDb.py > snapshotSmartCacheDb.txt` which created the `.txt` file in the `/home/user/` directory of the remote computer. From there I used `scp` to copy it to my local computer.

Comment: odd that a locally executed command can create a remote file using a  common simple pipe. But ,if it works - that's what matters. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Python to take a MySQL dump. You may be interested in [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). Run the following command:

```
mysqldump db_name > dump.sql
```

Other easier option for you may be to use `phpmyadmin` to export the database as an SQL file.

Comment: I added the comment so he knows of mysqldump in case he needs it. That doesn't mean he wants all the data.

Comment: I only have limited access to the database. I only really have access to a .py file that was dumped from the MySQL database. I have to take the table in the .py and create a .txt file from it.